# Adding Linear Constraint on python

Tags: julia, clp

I am trying to translate a julia code to python and I'm stuck to understand a function of linear programming using CLP in julia or Gurobi, the function is:

```
function setc(c)
    for i = 1:size(A, 1)
        m.linconstr[i].lb = float(c[i])
    end
```

Where `A` is a matrix, `lb` and `m`is the name of the model that is used is the lower bound. To be more specific I want to understand what is the meaning of m.linconstr[i]

Comment: Code you please edit the question so that the code appears as a separate block? Putting empty lines before and after should help with that.

Comment: Pure guess here, but I would read that as setting the lower bound of constraint indexed `i` as `c[i]`.

Comment: it makes sense to me, but i don't know can i write it in python as i've been struggling with it